# Finding the nth bit from pointer to a big block of memory

Tags: c

Let's say I have a pointer to a big block of memory
I want to get the nth bit to the right of the pointer

```
void* start = malloc(1024*1024*1024);
bool nthBit(int n)
{
   return (int)((char*)start + n / 8) & (1 << n % 8);
}
```

I want to do something like this, but ofc there is an error and doesn't compile cuz I can't cast the char* to int.
Is there a workaround or a simpler way?

Comment: You have to dereference `raw`, you are not doing so

Comment: "I can't cast the char* to int" - so just dereference the `char*` first... also, a `bool` should only be `0` or `1`, not `1 << n % 8`, so fix your comparison to return that.

Comment: `void* start =` `(char*)raw`  I think you meant either `start` or `raw` in both places.

Comment: Don't hard code '8'.  Although it's probably not really necessary any more for portability, it is far more obvious to the human reader if you use `CHAR_BIT` (in <limits.h>).  (And re: portability, I was thinking more about 8 vs 9, but I suspect there are some 16 bit machines.  So use it for portability.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close enough! I would:

```
bool nthBit(const void *raw, size_t n)
{
   return *((const unsigned char*)raw + n / CHAR_BIT) & (1 << (n % CHAR_BIT));
//        ^                                 ^^^^^^^^ - it will be 8, but communicates intent more clear
//        ^ - actually access the pointer by dereferencing it
}
```

> can't cast the char* to int. Is there a workaround or a simpler way?

Well, I assumed you want to nth bit of the memory the pointer points to. By casting `char*` to `int` as you did in your code you are manipulating the *value* of the pointer. To access memory where the pointer points to, you have to dereference it.

Comment: It's better to use `unsigned char` for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid long operations. Introduce intermediate variables which at the end of the day will be optimized out by the compiler.

```
bool nthBitp(void *ptr, size_t n)
{
   unsigned char *cptr = ptr;
   unsigned char byte = cptr[n / CHAR_BIT];

   return !!(byte & ( 1 << (n % CHAR_BIT)));
}
```

optimizing compilers will replace the `/` and `%` with bitwise operators when `CHAR_BIT` is the power of `2`

https://godbolt.org/z/bKs3hG

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
bool test_bit(uint32_t* array , uint32_t idx){                                                                                                                                                                 
    uint32_t seg = idx / (sizeof(uint32_t) * 8) ;                                                                                                                                                      
    uint32_t offset = idx % (sizeof(uint32_t) * 8);                                                                                                                                                                          
    uint8_t value = (array[seg] >> ((sizeof(uint32_t) * 8 - 1)  - offset)) & 0x1 ;                                                                                                                                                                      
    return value != 0 ;
}
```

With `idx` being your nth bit .

Comment: Why so complicate. And it is an UB when reding last `uint32_t` if the length is not dividable by sizeof(uint32_t) (you access the array out of bounds). Generally speaking DV